# Encryption&Decryption in Login System

Tags: android, encryption

I have a login system , but i want to encrypt password when sign up this system and write encrypted password to database , then when this user login again program receive encrypted pass from database decrypt match entered login password and go succesfull login.

my encrypted password writed succesfully to  database.
But when i receive from database not matched decrypted pass = entered password when login.

my codes :

SignUpactivity.java ( scoped encryption )

```
        String unsafetypass=args[1];
        Encryption encryption = Encryption.getDefault("Key", "Value", new byte[16]);
        String pass2 = encryption.encryptOrNull(unsafetypass);
```

Here pass2 is encrypted password writed in database no problem.

But here i must select from database encrypted password its ok i selected. But now i have to decrypt for match to login password.

Problem here : 
LoginActivity.java ( scoped decryption )

```
Encryption encryption = Encryption.getDefault("Key", "Value", new byte[16]);
Password =encryption.decryptOrNull(rs2.getString("Password")); //rs2 is resultset string from database...
```

Here password not matched with login password.Why ? Maybe it is about Encrytion variable ?

Comment: Try to log `String pass2 = encryption.encryptOrNull(unsafetypass)` and `rs2.getString("Password")` whether it is same or not.

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this Encryption class you're using? I cant seem to find it anywhere...

What may be easier, and even more secure, is using an SHA-256 hash as "encryption". Simply hash the password, store it in the server, and when the user tries to log in again, compare the hash stored by the server to the hash of the password he attempted to use. That way, the password is never sent through the network, and its almost impossible to reverse-hash SHA-256! Example for password storage:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Server.write(new String(hash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

For password comparison:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
passwordHash = Server.readLine();
if((new String(hash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).equals(passwordHash)) authentication.success();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for help, 256-bit more effective from my library , Actually i didnt trust this library :)

Comment: By the way i fixed my problem i dont need to decryption because when enter the login screen password already decrypted i must encrypt it and i have encryted this entered login password and compare with database encryted password when matched result true go login.. I hope helpful for another developers..Thank you for help again.

Comment: Exactly, you got it! no worries :)

Comment: You should never use a simple hash function to protect your user's passwords. You need to use a strong hashing scheme like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Be sure to use a high cost factor/iteration count. It is common to choose the cost so that a single iteration takes at least 100ms. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: I did my style encrypt yes it takes very long time about up to 10 seconds i must change my method i will try your advice thankss:)

Comment: unless you are the US government, using anything more powerful than SHA-256 is ridiculous. With common brute force and collision attack methods SHA-256 can be cracked with around 2^510 hashes, which very few people have the computational power and time to crack.